# Model visibility scope in security (ir.model.access.csv)

Tags: odoo

I’m trying to programmatically create a group with security permissions to be applied on a certain model.
I use (ir.model.access.csv) and an XML file.

[image]

I keep getting the error message:

**No matching record found for external id**

It happens if I define the permissions for an existing model not defined in my module (such as res_partner for example).

Is this how it works? Should I set permissions for the models created by my module only or can I set permissions for other models in the system?

Comment: In which module does the group `group_res_customer` exists?

Comment: the group: group_res_customer is a new one I'm trying to create in a custom module. This custom module has a many2one filed related to the res_partner model.

Comment: try to write the module name ahead of the group name **module_name.group_name**

Comment: I tried this but it keeps showing the same error: No matching record found for external id 'model_res_partner' in field 'Object'  ... It seems that the problem is that it can't reach the model because it's outside the scope.

Comment: First, Is your module dependency correct? Second, in the model name try to put as `base.model_res_partner`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once in odoo v8.0

Inherited modules have their permissions already defined in it's own folders, with their .csv and .xml files. So you don't need to set them. Probably you can inherit the permissions, but so far I haven't seen any modules that do that.

In my case, I only set the permissions for the modules I created and it worked.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Adding Access Rights to Already installed or other than your custom modules. 
add model name section as

```
 modulename.model_model_name
```

Sample csv line :-

```
access_manager_ir_conf,Manager Ir Conf,base.model_ir_config_parameter,estimate.group_estimate_manager,1,0,0,0
```